# Finding a lower bound independent of the probability which ensures the probability is on a given interval

Tags: probability

A coin, for which on any toss $\Bbb P(\text{head}) = p$, is tossed $n$ times and the quantity

$$\bar X_n =  \frac{\text{number of heads}}{n}$$
is calculated.

Find a lower bound on $n$ (that is independent of $p$) which will
ensure that $$\Bbb P(\bar X_n − 0.1 < p < \bar X_n + 0.1)\geq 0.9$$

I'm confused as to what this question is asking me and I'm not particularly sure how to start it. any help wold be appreciated.

Comment: The opening line of this post has no connection to the rest of it, The question is: Find a number $n$ such that if you flip a biased coin $n$ times, there is at least a 90% chance that the ratio of the number of heads to $n$ is within $0.1$ of the actual probability of getting a head.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_n)=\frac{p(1-p)}n\leq\frac1{4n}$. Now use Chebyshev's inequality.